# How to return a list with an extra field?

Tags: soql

For example, I need return a list of account, but want a extra field Label, it has same value as Name, like below

```
SELECT Id, Name, Name Label FROM Account LIMIT 10
```

But I cannot use alias, how can I do here?

Thanks

Comment: You can either retrieve field value directly or with aliasing,  not both as in your example.

Comment: I'm not following what you're actually asking for - you'd like to query a custom field called `Name_Label__c`?  Or maybe you'd like to give `Name` a different label to refer to it by?

Comment: I want to query an objects and return a list like below for LWC.  items = [{
    "label": "Western Sales Director",
    "name": "Western Sales Director"
}, {
    "label": "Eastern Sales Director",
    "name": "Eastern Sales Director"
}...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL is not SQL and is far more limited with what you can do (with some extensions to help you with object structuring). A query returns a list of SObjects. These have a defined set of fields, some of which may be dynamic and with an alias (such as with a use of the DISTANCE function) but most are simply the fields defined in the SObject schema.

There is the concept of an aggregate query where you get back a list of aggregate results. Note that these are NOT SObjects and are accessed completely differently in the Apex code receiving the results back. For example:

```
List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT Id Id, Name Name, Name Label FROM Account GROUP BY Id, Name];

System.debug(results[0].get('Id') + ' ' + results[0].get('Name') + ' ' + results[0].get('Label'));
```

Every field should be given an alias in this case, otherwise you have to use a default index-based name to access the values from the aggregate result.

All this said, I'm not really clear why you would want to do what you asked. It may be worth expanding your question to be more explicit in your needs (i.e. why you are doing this - what is the goal).

Comment: Great answer, didn't knew that we can have multiple alias of same field like for Name in your example.

Comment: Thanks, I know alias is only allowed on aggregate result, and there is a toLabel, but has limit on some fields too. What I tried to do is figuring out what is the right way is I want to return a list with certain fields. For example, I want to use the returned result on a lightning tree component, it need both name and label. In this case, how do I get list from an object and manipulate to make the result contains both name and label.

Comment: I guess I have to create new class with field name and label, and build a list to return